# How to pass an int to an Activity when created in a TabWidget in Android?

Tags: android, tabwidget

I started with the TabLayout tutorial from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

I created a ListActivity class (ListAct) to be used as a Tab. The only difference between the Tabs is the used Layout:
in the onCreate I use setContentView(R.layout.layout0) for the first Tab.
In the second I do setContentView(R.layout.layout1).
It seams a bit like a waste to use a different class for this, does it not?

Is there a way to pass the used Layout (int) while creating the Tab like this?

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListAct.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list0").setIndicator("List0",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists));
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different class is useful to create as the each tab can be used to trigger activities so each activity can be given to a specific tab.
a different file is helpful in keeping clarity in the code.
just imagine you have to look at the same project after months and you will have a tough time figuring things out.
so the proper way of implementing tabs is using a different file and activity for each tab you create .

Comment: Thanks. Helped enough to be able to do what I needed.